# Dojo integration with editor for autocompletion

Tags: javascript, ide, dojo

I am looking for any way or any editor so that I can get auto-completion of Dojo functions in my IDE. I did not find any. I am very handy with Eclipse. But i did not find any plugin for this kind of support. If anyone know anything please let me know. or If anyone know any IDE or Editor which can support this kind of auto-completion, please let me know.

Answer (score 2):

Komodo and Komodo Edit do : http://www.activestate.com/komodo-edit

Answer (score 2):

JetBrains makes a tool called WebStorm which comes highly recommended:

http://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/

If you're working in the J2EE world, you can get these features integrated with IDEA, which is their Java IDE.

Answer (score 1):

I believe [Aptana](http://www.aptana.com/), which is based on Eclipse, supports it. It can be used as a standalone application or an Eclipse plugin. See the following for further guidance.

https://wiki.appcelerator.org/display/tis/Using+JavaScript+Libraries

https://wiki.appcelerator.org/display/tis/JavaScript+Library+Support

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I like the Aptana plugins for Eclipse.

Comment: i have found a more recent version, dojo 1.7 at https://raw.githubusercontent.com/gigi81/studio3-sdk/master/tools/frameworks/dojo/1.7/api.sdocml